# OOP backend application architecture

Tags: oop, backend, software-design, separation-of-concerns

I work on a perl OOP non-web backend application dealing with measures sent by devices. I wanted to clearly separate data access and domain concerns.

So I organized my classes into 2 separate namespaces : "Controller" and "Model".

My question is, should I create a "Mesure" inside both namespaces knowing that "Mesure" objects creation is always triggered by data fetching from the DB ?

Thanks.

Comment: Model/Controller is a very low level pattern, when you actually ask about an IoT scenario. It also doesn't really help with the real use case. You have a *stream of events* that need processing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a quite broad question, but Measure seems a data structure containing mostly data so it should be in Model. It will have methods like getting/setting properties or some generic calculation functions possibly.

Controller seems more like using or measuring a Measure (from a Device?), so in that namespace I would expect classes/functions for handling/changing a Measure which interacts with a device.

Comment: Thank you. Doing so what mocking data mechanism would it be convenient to setup (for unit testing for example) ?

Comment: I do not have knowledge about mocking, but normally it is normal to build Model instances first, than Controller instances to use those; I expect for testing Controller it is likewise. Model instances probably are not     dependent on Controller instances, but Controller instances need Model instances to work.